# Dual external monitors?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I am trying to switch from using my desktop to my macbook pro as my primary machine.

I have 2 monitors (each 1600x1200 resolution) I'd like to use as external monitors for my macbook pro (from 2013).  Both monitors support VGA and DVI input (along with s-video and composite, although I've never used those before).

Looking at the laptop, it has 1 hdmi port, and 2 thunderbolt ports.

The 'about this mac' reports I'm using osX 10.10.4, with a early 2013 15-inch Retina display.  Graphics card is nVidia GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB.

How do I find out if this is possible?  If it is possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You can run one monitor off the HDMI port and another 2 off of the  Thunderbolt ports. You can get adapters for both of these.

There's more out there than this but here's one Apple sells.

http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB570LL/B/mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter

BTW: Thunderbolt ports can work Mini Display port adapters.

Comment: Is there enough video ram to drive that many pixels?  My concern is we bumped into this problem with my wife's (non-mac) laptop, and I don't want to get it all set up only to realize the video card can't cut it.

Comment: Yeah I have a mid 2012 macbook pro that I would drive dual 24" Apple Displays + the laptops own display. Sometimes I would use another 20" junk monitor out of the hdmi port when working on some video projects. So that's 4 screens total. So shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: That is excellent! :)